# remove dal reference from web project

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a 3 layer application and the layers are:
    Web: Presentation Layer (ASP.NET MVC) --> want to only see service layer
    BLL: Service Layer --> only sees DAL
    DAL: Data Access Layer --> Hold my Edmx
    iam using unit of work and repository as below :

```
    public interface IUnitOfWo
            {
                IGenericRepo<Actor,ActorDto> ActorRepo{ get; }
                void Save();
            }
```

here is implementation of IUnitOfWork

```
    public IGenericRepo<Actor, ActorDto> ActorRepo
                {
                    get { return actorRepo ??(actorRepo = new GenericRepo<NtierMvcAppEntities, Actor, ActorDto>()); }
                }
```

and WebApp i want to fetch data like this without using DAL :

```
     private IUnitOfWo _unitOfWork;

                public TestController(IUnitOfWo unitOfWork)
                {
                    _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
                }
                       public ActionResult Index()
                {
                    // get all models
                    List<ActorDto> modelList = _unitOfWork.ActorRepo.GetAll();

                    //  this line wont work without have reference of DAL.dll
                    return View(modelList);
                }
```

Comment: Did someone say _infinite monkeys_?  I think they're working on Hamlet just now

Comment: :S you can ask for more information !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason why you want to hide your domain model as well as your DAL from the presentation layer?

unless you have good reasons, you'd better keep it simple and expose it. You can still use view models to avoid using your EF entities in your views (and to make more efficient queries by projecting only the properties you need into your view models)

And I don't know why everybody want to implement their own unit of work and repository. An EF context is already a unit of work and a repository!